# How append a new index to dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like bellow, and I want to append `t` as a new row data to the `d1`, but it failed ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the row directly:

```
df1.loc['new_index'] = t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.append(df.iloc[1]/df.iloc[0], ignore_index=True)
```

Demonstration, df:

[image]

after appending:

[image]